# MySQL/PHP Results displayed out of order

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a crowd-rating site that randomly chooses episodes from a show from a list, and generates buttons for the user to click on, each indicating a vote for that episode.

I've found out, though, that for some reason, the first episode ("kitten") is not the first one on the page, even though that's what the display code seems to say it should be. This is not actually a problem, in that I can continue development without 'fixing' it, but it is an unintuitive result, and all things being equal I don't like to have things in my code that I don't understand.

```
$total_kittens_query = 'SELECT max(`id`) AS max FROM `kittens`';
$query_result = mysqli_query($link,$total_kittens_query);

$count = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result);

$random_kitten_one = mt_rand(1, $count['max']);
$random_kitten_two = mt_rand(1, $count['max']);

while($random_kitten_one == $random_kitten_two) {
    $random_kitten_two = mt_rand(1, $count['max']); // Prevent duplicates
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `kittens` WHERE `kittens`.`id`='" . $random_kitten_one . "' OR `kittens`.`id`='" . $random_kitten_two . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 2) {
    // Create a game
        $game_query = "INSERT INTO `games` (`kitten_one`, `kitten_two`, `winner`, `ip`) VALUES ('" . $random_kitten_one . "', '" . $random_kitten_two . "', -1, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link,$game_query);
    // Game table: id (auto_inc, int, 10), kitten_one (int, 10), kitten_two (int, 10), winner (int, 10), ip (varchar, 15)
    $game_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

    $kitten_one = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $kitten_two = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><th scope='row'>Name:</th>";
echo "<td>".$kitten_one['name']."</td><td>".$kitten_two['name']."</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Album:</th><td>".$kitten_one['album']."</td><td>".$kitten_two['album'].""; 
echo "</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Summary:</th><td>".$kitten_one['summary']."</td><td>".$kitten_two['summary']."</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Quote(s):</th><td>".$kitten_one['quotes']."</td><td>".$kitten_two['quotes']."</td></tr>
<tr><th scope='row'>Elo Rating:</th><td>".$kitten_one['elo']."</td><td>".$kitten_two['elo']."</td></tr></table>";
echo  "<table id='ratings' border='5' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Matches</th><th>Wins</th><th>Win Rate</th><th>Elo</th></tr>";
echo "</thead>";

    echo '<form action="?" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="game_id" value="', $game_id, '"><input type="hidden" name="kitten_id" value="', $kitten_one['id'], '"><input type="submit" value="Vote 4 ', $kitten_one['name'], '"></form>';
    echo '<form action="?" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="game_id" value= "', $game_id, '"><input type="hidden" name="kitten_id" value="', $kitten_two['id'], '"><input type="submit" value="Vote 4 ', $kitten_two['name'], '"></form>';
} else {
    die('Error in the matrix!');
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are after. The "First Episode ('kitten') " isn't much of a clue. How do you determine what episode an item is so you know what to apply ORDER BY on for correct field.

Comment: Looks like you want an ORDER BY clause in the $query SQL. Maybe ORDER BY id if there is an id column. Or do you mean something is unexpected about the formatting of the HTML table?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not 100% sure this is helpful, but the episodes are denoted by a numerical ID. 

The HTML table is the "problem" here, such as it is; it lists the episodes in order of ID, when I would expect it to be done in the order as the random number generator picked them, though (picking random_kitten_one, then random_kitten_two, from the max id).

Comment: @JamesGryphon Well what you could do is a test on the random numbers... If rand_1 < rand_2 - the normal default order would work or ORDER BY id DESC ...  if rand_1 > rand_2 ORDER BY id ASC So when building your query and keeping the ORDER BY as common, you'd just need to set a string to either DESC or ASC to your SQL string, then run it... Or as you only have TWO results, you could just perform the assignment on the same test as above. Make sense?

Comment: `when I would expect it to be done in the order as the random number generator picked them` you should not assume that any part of a query is executed in the order you write it, the actual execution sequence can be very different (e.g. the from clause is performed before the select clause). To guarantee a specific order you must use an `ORDER BY clause`

Comment: I thought I'd check back in to note that I was able to figure out a solution, and to note what I ended up doing. The old query picked kitten_one *or* kitten_two first, whichever came first -- which we can logically assume is going to be the one with the first ID. So that answers how that happened. So, my replacement query selects each individually in their proper order and merges them with a union.